# How can I retrieve the Installation Type via a Run Script in install4j?

Tags: install4j

The install4j APIs allow for getting installation components by ID and determining if they are selected in a script action.  I don't see a way to do that for installation type IDs.  I have a couple of installation types, where the component list is the same, but they need to be configured different based on type.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
(String)context.getVariable("sys.installationTypeId")
```

The reason why this is not in the context is that the installation type is not a fundamental concept in install4j, it is provided by the installation type screen. In fact, you could program the entire installation type functionality just with the public API.

Comment: This is great Ingo, I figured something had to be there.  I was able to work around this by the way, by creating empty hidden components associated with the types I needed to know about and using the component api. I suppose both options work, but will probably replace that work around now. I'm guessing the package would be slightly smaller if nothing else.